# How to I round the corners of ImageView for only on side fit to the parent layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

I am beginner to Android. Now I am learning how to design Android App properly. But I am having a problem with ImageView. I want to round the corners of ImageView but only for one side.

This image is what I want to get:

[image]

As you can see only left side corners of ImageView are rounded fitting to parent view.

This is what I am getting right now:

[image]

This is the XML layout for my list view row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/row_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/list_item_content_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_file_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-round-corners-on-an-android-imageview-with-this-hack/). But the padding is included for ImageView. But when I remove padding, it is not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should apply a transformation when loading the images. For example if you use picasso for loading imageas you could apply this transformation:

Base class:

```
public class RoundedCornersBitmap implements Transformation {

private static final float DEFAULT_RADIUS = 5.f;
private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
private static final int DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH = 3;

protected float mCornerRadius;
protected int mBorderColor;
protected int mStrokeWidth;

@Override
public String key() {
    return "roundedCorners()";
}

public RoundedCornersBitmap() {
    mCornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    mStrokeWidth = DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH;
}

public RoundedCornersBitmap(float cornderRadius, int borderColor, int strokeWidth) {
    mCornerRadius = cornderRadius;
    mBorderColor = borderColor;
    mStrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
}

@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(mStrokeWidth, mStrokeWidth, (bitmap.getWidth() - mStrokeWidth), bitmap.getHeight()
            - mStrokeWidth);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, paint);
    //canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    bitmap.recycle();
    return output;
}

/**
 * @return the mCornerRadius
 */
public float getCornerRadius() {
    return mCornerRadius;
}

/**
 * @param mCornerRadius
 *            the mCornerRadius to set
 */
public void setCornerRadius(float mCornerRadius) {
    this.mCornerRadius = mCornerRadius;
}

/**
 * @return the mBorderColor
 */
public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor;
}

/**
 * @param mBorderColor
 *            the mBorderColor to set
 */
public void setBorderColor(int mBorderColor) {
    this.mBorderColor = mBorderColor;
}

/**
 * @return the mStrokeWidth
 */
public int getStrokeWidth() {
    return mStrokeWidth;
}

/**
 * @param mStrokeWidth
 *            the mStrokeWidth to set
 */
public void setStrokeWidth(int mStrokeWidth) {
    this.mStrokeWidth = mStrokeWidth;
}

}
```

LeftRoundedCornersBitmap:

```
public class LeftRoundedCornersBitmap extends RoundedCornersBitmap {

    public LeftRoundedCornersBitmap() {
        super();
    }

    public LeftRoundedCornersBitmap(float cornderRadius, int borderColor, int strokeWidth) {
        super(cornderRadius, borderColor, strokeWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

       final Paint paint = new Paint();
       final Rect rect = new Rect(mStrokeWidth, mStrokeWidth, (bitmap.getWidth() - mStrokeWidth), bitmap.getHeight()
            - mStrokeWidth);
       final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
       final Rect topRightRect = new Rect(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
       final Rect bottomRect = new Rect(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

       paint.setAntiAlias(true);
       paint.setColor(mBorderColor);
       paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

       canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
       canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, paint);
       canvas.drawRect(topRightRect, paint);
       canvas.drawRect(bottomRect, paint);

       paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
       bitmap.recycle();
       return output;
   }
}
```

Picasso dependency in the gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).transform(new LeftRoundedCornersBitmap()).into(youImageView);
```

Comment: I am using volley. This is my first project.

Comment: The images are from network and I just parsed url into image.

Comment: Also with picasso you can load images from network. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: An advantage is that you can apply transformations on images before showing them.

Comment: So can I get example of parsing the image from url and use this class together with it ?

Comment: Cannot extends  RoundedCornersBitmap  class . Cause it cannot be found. But loading image using picasso is working fine . Even more simple than volley.

Comment: I have added the code for RoundedCornersBitmap in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml and set it to your main layout background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>    

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
             /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
</shape>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<ImageView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/row_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_margin="10"//add this
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Comment: main layout background means the background of my list view item ?

Comment: yes your list view row, change this android:background="@drawable/list_row_bg" to the new xml

Comment: I already set a background with radius like it to my list item layout.

Comment: just copy my xml to list_row_bg.xml and try

Comment: No It is not working. I added the screenshot of your answer editing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For that you will have to create a drawable xml and set that as background of the view to which you want to give this shape.

```
<corners 
  android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="0.1dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Glide 3.7 =>

```
val multiLeftTopCorner: MultiTransformation<Bitmap> = MultiTransformation(
    RoundedCornersTransformation(context, 15f, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP_RIGHT),
    RoundedCornersTransformation(context, 15f, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP_LEFT)
)

Glide.with(context)
    .load(IMAGE_URL)
    .asBitmap()
    .transform(multiLeftTopCorner)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
    .into(imageView)
```

If your using latest Glide version 4.13

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .transform(new GranularRoundedCorners(75, 75, 0, 0))
            .into(imageView);
```

**But the better option is ShapeableImageView(Material library com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView)**

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />
    
imageView.setShapeAppearanceModel(imageView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
.toBuilder().setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 10)
            .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 10)
            .build())
```

You can also apply in the xml the shapeAppearanceOverlay parameter:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/customRroundedImageView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />
```

with:

```
<style name="customRoundedImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>   
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">8dp</item>
  </style>
```